# How to detect what class an instance is from in flash(as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I am relatively new to Flash and I am trying to make a little game.
For that I need to detect, if the player clicked on a plane or a bird.

I am spawning them with addChild and the name of each instance is generated.
The eventlistener is attached to the instance.

I tried detecting it like that, but it doesn't seam to work.
It detects the clicking (it prints out the shot: instance but not the trace commands in the if), but not was was clicked on.

```
function shoot(e: MouseEvent): void {
    trace("shot: "+ e.target.name);
    if (e.target is Plane) {
        trace("shot plane");
        e.target.parent.removeChild(e.target);
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
    if (e.target == Bird) {
        trace("shot bird");
        score += 1;
        e.target.parent.removeChild();
    }
}
```

Does anybody have a tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `e.currentTarget` rather than `e.target`.

```
if (e.currentTarget is Plane) {
    ...
}
if (e.currentTarget is Bird) {
    ...
}
```

The **current target** of an event is a reference to the item you added the event listener to.  The **target**, on the other hand, is the item actually clicked (which could be the same as current target, or a descendant/child object of it)

You can use `getQualifiedClassName` to check the object type:

```
trace(flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget));
```